# How to not have scrollview "pull to refresh" drag the entire screen down on iOS [React Native]

Tags: ios, react-native, scrollview, pull-to-refresh

On Android pull to refresh shows a loading circle on the screen. on iOS the entire contents of you screen is shifted down, loading circle appear, then content shifts back as illustrated below.

(left is iOS example, right is android example)

[image]

My question is can I disable the screen shifting down and back up on iOS? I still need the pull to refresh functionality from scrollview but not the animation that takes place on iOS.

Basically I have a top navbar that is fixed, I have a weather component that is part of scroll view.

[image]

I want the weather component to disappear as the user scrolls and to refresh when the user pulls to refresh. The issue is that only on iOS pulling to refresh drags the contents of the screen and the weather component "detaches". This is not an issue on android since the pull to refresh animation doesn't shift the screens contents.

[image]

```
<Screen unsafe>
    <ScrollView
        refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={isRefreshing} onRefresh={handleRefresh} />}
        keyboardAware
      >
        <AirQuality />

        //...many other components

    </ScrollView>
</Screen>
```

Is there maybe a different way to approach this? I would appreciate any insights!

Comment: In iOS the pull to refresh is linked to the list not to the screen. So if you want to change what is the standard behaviour of iOS apps you will have to code it yourself. You can use a drag gesture and add a activity indicator on top of view.